# How to secure an API written in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, security, obfuscation, source-code-protection

This is a variation on an existing question in SO about securing/obfuscating .Net applications in general.

I'm developing an API in C# that includes some algorithms I'm keen to protect. 
I understand no method will be perfect, but what's the generally accepted method for doing this?

I'd like my clients to be able to code against the API but I don't want them to reverse engineer what's inside (at least I don't want to make it easy for them).

If I obfuscate the code, won't that also obfuscate the API?

We're looking at smartAssembly any thoughts comments on the product would be appreciated.

Comment: Jeepers I didn't expect so many responses so quickly.  I'll look into what smartAssembly does with public methods.  It seems like an obvious thing in light of these responses.

I'd love to not hand out the API but we're looking to make use of the client CPU for processing and not the CPU on the server

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an option for you, but consider protecting the algorithms by never handing them out.  Can you provide the processing through a webservice, .asmx or WCF?

AFAIK, there is no absolutely perfect way to protect your code but obfuscation and encryption can make it more difficult than it's worth to reverse-engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscate it. Obfuscation tools don't obfuscate the public API as that would break external code that depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

A good code obfuscator will take a lis tof exceptions to not obfuscate and IN GENERAL have a switch to ONLY obfuscate implementation details and not touch the public API (classes, properties etc.). So, if you coded right (facade public, all implementation details non-public) it should do a good job.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned smartAssembly. There is also [Dotnetreactor](http://www.eziriz.com), [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) and an open source obfuscator: [sharpobfuscator](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpObfuscator).