# How to obfuscate a dll in c# and then use it to make another program

Tags: c#, obfuscation

im currently using ConfuserEx to obfuscate most of my programs. But now i want to sell someone a DLL, but im having a hard time obfuscating the DLL and then being able to use it on Visual Studio.
Is this a impossible thing or can it be done with pinvoke or something more advanced?

Comment: Don't obfuscate the API, see [How to secure an API written in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2463241/33499)

Comment: Obfuscation can not protect your code, just can make the life for the hacker a little bit harder. The only thing that can protect your intellectual property is *law*

Comment: i know that... but theres no reason to not do it if you can do it... its not going to be a big program but i dont want script kiddies to just crack it if i wanted that i wouldnt be selling right?

Comment: @Diego you want to sell a library(DLL), so you can not obfuscate the API(public methods). What would be the reason to obfuscate other internal methods? Better, write a web service and sell a membership to your customer.

Comment: @Eser becouse the DLL is going to be a login system... if they break the login its going to be my fault becouse he forgot to obfuscate or something...

Comment: @Diego The security of a login system should absolutely not depend on whether someone has access to the source.

Comment: @Diego think SSL, the `s` in https. It is a well known code. And its security doesn't depend of hiding the source code...

Comment: @Eser i honestly never done anything with https are there any resources you can link?

Comment: @Diego It was just an example to show that the security of an algorithm doesn't depend on its being hidden.